# Implement abstract factory using generic class and interface

Tags: c#, abstract-class, abstract-factory

I want to implement an abstract factory (with singletons) and use it in my code with concrete instances of `TType` and `TInterfaceType` to be mapped to.

Here is my current code:

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory<TType, TInterfaceType> where TType : new() where TInterfaceType : class
{
    private TInterfaceType objectTtype;
    public TInterfaceType getInstance()
    {
        try
        {
            if (objectTtype == null)
            {
                objectTtype = new TType();
            }

            return objectTtype;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> Cannot implicitly coonvert type TType to TInterfaceType

How can I implement an abstract class with the method definition using a class and its corresponding interface. For example I want to use it as follows:

```
ConcreteFactory : AbstractFactory<ConcreteClass, IConcreteClass>
```

Comment: Please remove `catch (Exception e) { throw e; }`. This is not only useless but actively harmful, since it breaks the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a constraint saying that `TType` must inherit from `TInterfaceType`:

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory<TType, TInterfaceType> 
            where TType : TInterfaceType, new()
            where TInterfaceType : class
```

Now the compiler knows that `TType` inherits from `TInterfaceType` and `objectTtype` is therefor assignable (and returnable) to `TInterfaceType`.